# Storing user input (STRING) into Array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

Alright so for my computer science course I have to make two separate arrays, fill them with user input from two separate methods. I'm stuck on actually making the input from my code be stored in my two arrays. I don't even know where to start with it. I've tried searching for examples, but I haven't found anything. I am also rather new to coding.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
 /**
  * @author SH
  *
  */
  public class SearchSort {

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public void inputFavoriteMovies(){
    System.out.println("Enter 6 of your favorite movies");
    int x = 0;
    while(x<6){
    String movies = console.nextLine();
    x++;
    }
}
public void inputFavoriteMusic(){
    System.out.println("Enter 5 of your Favorite Songs");
    int y = 0;
    while(y<5){
        String music = console.nextLine();
        y++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    new SearchSort().inputFavoriteMovies();
    new SearchSort().inputFavoriteMusic();

    String[] myFavoriteMovies = new String[6];


    String[] myFavoriteMsuic = new String[5];
 }

}
```

Comment: If you haven't found anything you haven't researched enough. You're currently parsing strings, and then you do nothing. You might want to make your String[] arrays class variables to make them visible to your methods. Further reading on that: scopes. Also, I don't think people use `console` any more. Maybe `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`

Comment: You don't want to try to code everything and then run it all at once. It's like building a car: you wouldn't finish the whole thing and try to run it because if it doesn't run, you don't know what's working and what's not working. Start with each individual part of the program and work on it until it works exactly as you'd like it to and combine working parts until you have a final product.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ He's not using console, it's just the name of the variable. He's using the `Scanner` class. Kind of confusing, hehe

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the changes I made below to your code and my comments related to each. If you wanted to make this quite a bit more flexible, use an ArrayList inside the methods and let the user enter as many as the want and use the .add() method of ArrayList to add each entry the user types. You'd have to come up with some sort of "sentinel" value that the user types when they are done (an empty string would work; you'd have to then check the inputValue.Length() of the string they entered and compare to 0 and exit a while loop once that length == 0). Then, you could use toArray() of ArrayList and convert it to an array that you then return to the calling code. That would give you a very dynamic arrangement and quite a bit more flexibility. You may not have learned about ArrayList yet but in all likelihood, you will fairly soon.

Hope this helps and good luck!

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
     /**
      * @author SH
      *
      */
      public class SearchSort {

    /*

    Since your code is essentially linear in nature (and not truly object-oriented), it's probably best to make it all static. You'll note I added the static modifier to the 2 methods you created along with the console declaration.

    */

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void inputFavoriteMovies(String[] storage){
/*
    For both of these methods, it makes sense to pass an array into them and then use the passed array for storage. Since arrays are essentially pass by reference, when you make changes to the array in this method, the array that was passed in will be modified when you return from this code.

Using the length of the array for both the prompt and the loop control helps to reduce the "index out of bounds" errors that may otherwise occur. It would actually be a little better to code this as a for loop:

for (int x=0; x < storage.length; x++ ) {
<insert all the code>
} // end for

*/
        System.out.println("Enter " + storage.length + " of your favorite movies");
        int x = 0;
        while(x < storage.length){
        storage[x] = console.nextLine();
        x++;
        }
    }

/*
comments here are essentially identical to those above.
*/

    public static void inputFavoriteMusic(String[] storage){
        System.out.println("Enter " + storage.length + " of your Favorite Songs");
        int y = 0;
        while(y < storage.length){
            storage[y] = console.nextLine();
            y++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

/*
Here in main, you basically declare an array as large as you want. Since you are now using methods that look at the length of the array, the code is slightly more abstract and gives you a tad more flexibility in design since it's not hard-coded
*/

        String[] myFavoriteMovies = new String[6];

// After declaring the array, pass it to the input method you created earlier. When that 
// method returns, the array will contain the values the user entered.

        inputFavoriteMovies(myFavoriteMovies);

// same as above - declare an array, then pass it to your input method.
        String[] myFavoriteMusic = new String[5];
        inputFavoriteMusic(myFavoriteMusic);

/* now, if you want to print the results, you'd do a pair of for loops that iterate
   over each array and output the results. For a bit more elegance, you could use
   this form of the for loop:

   for (String userInput : myFavoriteMovies) {
System.out.println(userInput);
}

for (String userInput : myFavoriteMusic) {
System.out.println(userInput)
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the arrays before running the input methods, instead of afterwards.  Then, as each string is input, put the string in the appropriate array.